# Get the total of complete column of gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am Using asp.net grid view and i have one column in that namely Calories and i want to show whole caloreis total at the top. i used the following code:

```
            int count = grdViewSample.Rows.Count;
            double totCalories = 0;
            Label lblCalories = new Label();


            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdViewSample.Rows)
            {
                lblCalories = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCalories");
                totCalories = totCalories + Convert.ToDouble(lblCalories.Text);

            }
            lblTotalCaloreis.Text = lblTotalCaloreis.Text + " " + totCalories;
```

and my problem is that the calories total get changed by paging and i want total caloreies available in grid view.
Thanks

Comment: This is logical, you need to calculate the calories, out side Gridview with an sql question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Instated of using 
grid view row property retrive no of rows from the data set directly because row property changes with the paging

     foreach (DataRow row in dsFood.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            totCal += Convert.ToDouble(row["calories"]);
                        }
                        lblCalories.Text = " " + totCal;
```